# AI: What kind of process would sites like Wit use to train Natural language

Tags: regex, nlp, artificial-intelligence, wit.ai

I am working on a project where I would like to achieve a sense of natural language understanding. However, I am going to start small and would like to train it on specific queries.

So for example, starting out I might tell it:

songs.

Then if it sees a sentence like "Kanye Wests songs" it can match against that.

BUT then I would like to give it some extra sentences that could mean the same thing so that it eventually learns to be able to predict unknown sentences into a set that I have trained it on.

So I might add the sentence: "Songs by

And of course  would be a database of names it can match agains.

I came across a neat website, Wit.ai that does something like I talk about. However, they resolve their matches to an intent, where I would like to match it to a simplified query or BETTER a database like query (like facebook graph search).

I understand a context free grammar would work well for this (anything else?). But what are good methods to train several CFG that I say have similar meaning and then when it sees unknown sentences it can try and predict.

Any thoughts would be great.

Basically I would like to be able to take a natural language sentence and convert it to some form that can be run better understood to my system and presented to the user in a nice way. Not sure if there is a better stackexchange for this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To begin with, I think SO is quite well-suited for this question (I checked Area 51, there is no stackexchange for NLP).

Under the assumption that you are already familiar with the *usual* training of PCFG grammars, I am going to move into some specifics that might help you achieve your goal:

Any grammar trained on a corpus is going to be dependent on the words in that training corpus. The poor performance on unknown words is a well-known issue in not just PCFG training, but in pretty much any probabilistic learning framework. What we *can* do, however, is to look at the problem as a paraphrasing issue. After all, you want to group together sentences that have the same *meaning*, right?

In recent research, detecting sentences or phrases that have the same (or similar) meaning have employed a technique known as as **distributional similarity**. It aims at improving probability estimation for unseen cooccurrences. The basic concept is

> *words or phrases that share the same distribution—the same set of words in the same context in a corpus—tend to have similar meanings.*

You can use only intrinsic features (e.g. production rules in PCFG) or bolster such features with additional semantic knowledge (e.g. ontologies like [FreeBase](http://www.freebase.com/)). Using additional semantic knowledge enables generation of more complex sentences/phrases with similar meanings, but such methods usually work well only for specific domains. So, if you want your system to work well only for music, it's a good idea.

Reproducing the actual distributional similarity algorithms will make this answer insanely long, so here's a link to an excellent article:

[Generating Phrasal and Sentential Paraphrases: A Survey of Data-Driven Methods](http://aclweb.org/anthology/J/J10/J10-3003.pdf) by Madnani and Dorr.

For your work, you will only need to go through section 3.2: *Paraphrasing Using a Single Monolingual Corpus*. I believe the algorithm labeled as 'Algorithm 1' in this paper will be useful to you. I am not aware of any publicly available tool/code that does this, however.

Comment: This looks very useful! Thanks. Do you happen to know of any open source implementations of this?

Comment: No, I am afraid not. In fact, I have been coding up a generic framework for distributional similarity myself. But it's not very likely that it will be in a usable state soon :-( ... in the mean time, if you happen to find an implementation, please do share your finding here.

Comment: I will for sure! Thanks for your help. I'll see what I can make from that paper :)

Comment: @Jonovono what framework did you end up using?  Or did you build your own?